# GWT module name for client component test

Tags: java, unit-testing, gwt, junit

I'm trying to write a test for client-side GWT component.
My `gwt.xml` file is placed in `subproject-name/src/main/resources/editor.gwt.xml`. I expect my module to be named `main.resources.editor`. I wrote a test:

```
public class PlacementPageTest extends GWTTestCase {

    PlacementPage testee = new PlacementPage();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        testee.activate();
    }

    @Override
    public String getModuleName() {
        return "main.resources.editor";
    }
}
```

I'm getting error stating: `ERROR: GWT.create() is only usable in client code!...`

Other answers I found suggest that I supplied a wrong module name. How do I find the right module name?

EDIT: when I try to call `GWT.getModuleName()` I get a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.getModuleName()Ljava/lang/String;`

Comment: Module name will be editor

Answer (score 0):

A module is defined by an XML descriptor file ending with the extension “`.gwt.xml`”, and the name of that file determines the name of the module.
 For example,if you have a file named

```
subproject-name/src/main/resources/editor.gwt.xml
```

then the Module name will be **editor**